# Assign an image to a header of a navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-navigationview

I am trying to recover data from the database (Firebase) and assign this data to the user page, exactly in the header in the navigation drawer.

I created an XML header and included the header in activity_main where I created the navigation drawer
In the header, I have a vision of images and two textview.

The code of the activity_main:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_layout" />


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"

        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now for Java, I created a class in which I recover user data from the database

```
    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();
        mUserData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(current_uid);

    mUserData.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
            status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
            thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
        }
```

So, in the main activity, I want to assign the image, user name and status to the navigation header.

```
    //NavigationView
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    UserData userData = new UserData();(ImageView)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewUserImage);
    TextView nav_userName = (TextView)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
    TextView nav_userStatus = (TextView)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserStatus);

    nav_userName.setText(userData.name);
    nav_userStatus.setText(userData.status);
```

As a result, I have the application crashed when I run the app. I do not know if the way I'm using to get the image or textview in the header is the problem or something else.

This is my first app, my code a bit 'messy so I did not include the complete code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer,

```
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    ImageView nav_userImage = header.findViewById(R.id.imageViewUserImage);
    TextView nav_userName = header.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
    TextView nav_userStatus = header.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserStatus);
```

This solved the problem, needed to point to the header view index.
Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the userData.name and userData.status values before setting the values. I am thinking both of them are null.

Answer (score 0):

You better find your views inside NavigationDrawer using DrawerLayout as following

```
TextView nav_userName = (TextView)drawer.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
TextView nav_userStatus = (TextView)drawer.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserStatus);
```

instead of

```
TextView nav_userName = (TextView)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
TextView nav_userStatus = (TextView)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserStatus);
```